# Jetpack compose best practice to create multi page forms (like with fragments)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-jetpack-compose

I want a user to create an object by filling out textfields but my object is large and the amount of textfields would imply creating a long scollable screen of textfields, checkboxes etc. So instead I want to divide the object instantiation process into several smaller and logically connected screens (or tabs) that the user can progress through via a "next" button until he eventually submits the object in the last of these screens. I want these screens to share the same viewmodel as they are all taking part in the instantiation of the same object and I want the user to only be able to access the next screen If he previously filled in the minimum required fields in the previous screen, with screens siding out to the left once they are done (just as fragments would). I want to avoid navigating to new screens to achieve the desired effect as I feel this would add unnecessary complexity

While I can easily think about a way to hide and animate columns using Compose in order to achieve the desired look and feel, I wonder if there is already a pre-existing composable or a best practice to achieve the fragment like behaviour I am looking for in Compose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found what I was looking for. It turns out the solution consists in making use of nested `NavGraphs`. I provided a solution in this Answer to a very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76076151/10637400

I hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

Using nested `NavGraphs` works just fine, though it is said to be a bad practice.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).