# Jetpack Compose Passing a ViewModel Between Multiple Pages but Removing when Out of Scope

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, viewmodel, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation, jetpack-compose-navigation

This is what I am trying to Achieve (noting I am quite new to Jetpack Compose):

Jetpack Compose April 2023. The date is important as I’m looking for the latest best practise.
I have tried many different examples, but they either don’t work or are now considered to be bad practice.

The Use Case:

1. MainActivity: Does whatever basic setup, then using NavHost opens the first page called 'HomePage'.
2. HomePage has multiple buttons that go off and do different tasks.
3. The first (only one considered here) of those tasks is a multi-page form (multiple pages) using a shared ViewModel. Let’s call them 'FormPageViewModel', 'FormPage1', 'FormPage2' and 'FormPage3'.
4. So on the HomePage I have clicked on the ;Create Form button and I am now looking at the FormPage1. Now in there I can do something I think like:

```kotlin
    // Create a new one or find one that already exist (it shouldn’t at this point for note).
    val formPageViewModel = ViewModel<FormPageViewModel>()
```

5. Now I go backwards and forwards through my form pages filling stuff in. I might click a cancel (or even a back button from FormPage1) button returning to the HomePage or I may complete the form with a button on the last page that then saves it to json (not relevant here) and it returns to the home page.

Where I am struggling is getting rid of 'Destroying / Removing / Deleting / Your Preferred Term' the FormPageViewModel when I return to the HomePage. Basically it should be as if it had never been instantiated and will only be instantiated if we open the FormPage1 again.

Now as I have said already above I have tried quite a few ways from examples that don't seem to work anymore or are considered bad practice. I debated creating two Activities but even this seems to be frowned upon (though it does work).

I can also create the ViewModel in the Activity and pass it to the composables with the navigation code and probably even destroy the ViewModel but this seems very messy and again seems to be frowned upon In a few places I am reading.

I am also for the moment trying to avoid Hilt and DI until I get from a raw (ish) point of view how to do it and what’s going on before adding more abstraction.

Comment: I'm a bit biased when it comes to `ViewModel` but I prefer to save portion of the data of each page of the form into DB until it's fully complete.

Comment: Each to their own but that creates a lot of unneeded code and you also have to start cleaning up the database as well. It can help if you want to continue where the user left off on battery failure etc but in this case any failure I want the form started again  from the beginning, and no DB clean-up required. It's not right or wrong to do it with a DB but not my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

In compose, you need to think different as thinking in views with lifecycles as Activity or Fragments, these ones can attach viewmodels by delegates using `activityViewModels` or `viewModels` , in compose, the lifecycle of a composable is the time it enters in a composition, recomposes and exits the composition.

This is event/state based and you need to hold your instances where the composition happens once to prevent duplication of instances.

When you create your `NavigationGraph`, you will be creating this composable only once, you can then create your viewmodel inside of it and pass it inside every `composable(route)` function you need this viewmodel.

In compose we can make use of something called `DisposableEffect` which will trigger in onDispose (when the composable leaves the composition)

At this time you can get rid of every data that this composable has saved inside of the viewmodel when you come back. But you can keep the same instance for both of them.

You can read here https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#disposableeffect

### Pseudocode

```
NavigationGraph(navController: NavigationController) {

 val viewmodel: SharedViewmodel = viewModel() 

 NavHost(...) {
  composable(route1) {
    YourFirstComposable(viewmodel)
 }
  composable(route2) {
  YourSecondComposable(viewmodel)
 }
}
```

Inside each of your destinations that uses this viewmodel, use the `DisposableEffect` to get rid of data inside your viewmodel, do cleanups, etc.

As you can see above, there is no need of scoping your `sharedViewmodel` to your activity.

Comment: I was under the impression (maybe wrongly) that in the new Jetpack Compose it is bad practice to pass a view model into a composable as a parameter.

Comment: I also think NavigationGraph isn't used now in the latest navigation system. It seems to be a navigation fun within the NavHost.

Comment: To be honest what you are saying and what seems to be the new way of doing it is why I am getting so confused as the demos out there and tutorials etc are all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently been struggling with the same challenge and I think I have finally found the way to create your multi-paged form all the while using DI (hilt) and having the form use the same viewmodel across pages.

You need to read up on Nested `NavGraphs` and realize that you can have several of them and even place them inside of a `Scaffold` (so that you, for example, keep a given `top` or `bottomBar` and just navigate through the `content` part of the `Scaffold`). The result being something similar to what we used to achieve with Fragments in the old declarative UI system.

In my case I host my main `NavGraph` in my `MainActivity` like so:

```
setContent {
        MyTheme {
            // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
         Surface(
             modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
             color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
         ) {
             val navController = rememberNavController()
             NavHost(
                 navController = navController,
                 startDestination = Screen.EntryScreen.route
             ) {
                  composable(route = Screen.EntryScreen.route) {
                        EntryScreen(navController = navController)
                  }
                  composable(route = Screen.PublishLot.route) {
                     PublishLot(mainNavController = navcontroller) //this is where the form is
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Now a peak into my `PublishLot` multipage form `@Composable`

```
@Composable
fun PublishLot(
   mainNavController: NavHostController,
   viewModel: PublishLotViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {

   val navController: NavHostController= rememberNavController()
   Scaffold(topBar = {
      CenterAlignedTopAppBar(title = {
          Text(text = "Publish Lot")
      })
   }) { padding ->
    Surface(modifier = Modifier.padding(padding)) {
        NavHost(
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = "form/page1"
        ) {
            composable(route = "form/page1") {
                Page1(navController = navController, viewModel = viewModel)
            }
            composable(route = "form/page2") {
                Page2(navController = navController, viewModel = viewModel, doOnFinished ={mainNavController.popBackStack()})
            }
        }

    }

}
}
```

As you can see I am simply creating a new `NavGraph` inside the content of my `PublishLot` form `Scaffold` and instantiating a new `NavController` (this is important, it wont work with the same `NavController` from the main `NavGraph`).

Notice that I use hilt to inject my viewModel into `PublishLot` but then pass it explicitly to both pages in my form. This means the state in my viewModel is not affected by navigating through the pages. And that pressing the backbutton leads you to the previous page in your form as one would expect.

I am still passing the `mainNavController` to the `PublishLot` composable so that I can pop the `backStack` on it once the form is filled thereby eliminating the `PublishLotViewModel`  instance that hilt created for me.

Let me know If this satisfies your requirements